# Sum of Stieltjes constants

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Does anyone know of any papers or resources dealing with the following question: For which values of $s=\sigma+it$ does the following sum of Stieltjes constants hold,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(s-1)^n=0,$$
where $\gamma_n$ is the $n$-th Stieltjes constant. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html) for information on the Stieltjes constants. I'm investigating when we have $\zeta(s)=1/(s-1)$ for $s\neq 1$ and thought this might help me given that
$$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n(s-1)^n.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the answer of Manzoni, the *Mathematica* command

> s[theta_, eps_, k_] := ZetaZero[k] + eps Exp[I theta]
>
> Plot[{Abs[1/(s[theta, .1, 1] - 1)],    Abs[Zeta[s[theta, .1, 1]]]},
>   {theta, 0, 2 Pi},   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red],
>   Directive[Thick, Green]}]

Generates this plot

[image: plot]

This shows that 
$$
\frac{1}{|s-1|}<|\zeta(s)|
$$
for $s$ on the circle of radius $.1$ around the lowest nontrivial Riemann zero $\rho=1/2+i14.13\ldots$.

By Rouche's Theorem, $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(s)-1/(s-1)$ have the same number of zeros inside the circle, namely $1$.

One could presumably do this for higher zeros as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know papers about your question but some numerical investigations return zeros near the Riemann zeros (because $\frac 1{s-1}$ is small for Riemann's zeros and of the smooth character of $\zeta'$ near $\zeta$ zeros) :

\begin{array} {llll}
&0.5+14.1347251417i&\mapsto &0.47940300622352\cdots&+14.04751638282159\cdots i\\
&0.5+21.0220396387 i&\mapsto &0.507180820934280248966\cdots&+20.980648953392265333\cdots i\\
&0.5+25.0108575801i&\mapsto &0.4893602291391196345\cdots&+24.9838122121001409936\cdots i\\
\end{array}

To find the approximative value of these zeros let's consider the first order expansion of $\zeta$ near one of its zeros $s_i$ :
$$\zeta(s_i+\epsilon_i)=\zeta(s_i)+\epsilon_i\zeta'(s_i)+O(\epsilon_i^2)$$
Since $\zeta(s_i)=0$ and since you want $\ \zeta(s_i+\epsilon_i)=\frac 1{s_i+\epsilon_i-1}\ $ you will have :
$$\frac 1{s_i+\epsilon_i-1}\approx \epsilon_i\zeta'(s_i)$$
and, to first order, the zeros will be nearly :
$$s_i+\epsilon_i \approx s_i+\frac 1{\zeta'(s_i)(s_i-1)}$$
With the values of $\zeta$ and $\zeta'$ for the three first zeros we get the approximate table :

\begin{array} {ll}
&0.482882 &+ 14.0472i\\
&0.508179 &+ 20.9810i\\
&0.489891 &+ 24.9835i\\
\end{array}

Not sure it will help much...