# The sum $\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}+\frac{1}{\ln(4)}+...$ is divergent. Find the regularized evaluation

Tags: riemann-zeta, divergent-series, regularization

By considering the integral Zeta function

$$F(s)=s+\frac{1}{2^s\ln(2)}+\frac{1}{3^s\ln(3)}+\frac{1}{4^s\ln(4)}+...$$

Evaluate

$$\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}+\frac{1}{\ln(4)}+...$$

EDIT:

There has clearly been much confusion here. I am asking for the analytic continuation of the integral Zeta function at 0. I am asking for the sum of the series in the sense that

$$1+2+3+...=-\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is not homework in case your interested. I know the solution to this will probably involve some complex analysis which is beyond my knowledge at the moment. Hence my question.

Comment: F(s)=2^(-s)/ln(2)+3^(-s)/ln(3)+4^(-s)/ln(4)+... at s=0, The integral of the Riemann Zeta function.

Comment: Maybe you should put "regularization" in the title. Everybody is just repeating how obvious the divergence is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sum is of course divergent (as proved by others).

But the idea is probably to use [zeta regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization) and get a formal derivation  like :
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}(\zeta(x)-1)\,dx&=\int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{n^x}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x\ln(n)}\,dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left.\frac1{\ln(n)\,n^x}\right|_{x=0}^{\infty}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{\ln(n)}\\
\end{align}
From the simple pole of $\zeta(x)$ at $x=1$ we should write our 'regularized sum' as the Cauchy principal value of the integral :
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{\ln(n)}=PV \int_0^{\infty}(\zeta(x)-1)\,dx\\=-0.243238342890980755415059\cdots$$
(if I didn't make an error...)

For numerical evaluation use $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to+\infty}\int_0^N \zeta(x)-1-\frac  1{x-1}\,dx+\ln(N-1)$.

Comment: Hmm, the term $\zeta(x)- {1 \over x-1}$ occured so often lately in my exercises that I think an "incomplete zeta" function should become some standard function in the handbooks (and software). For such an "incomplete zeta" there is also a power series nicely converging at small absolute values of the argument...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: ... so that 'Stieltjes function' could be appropriate! :-) (Stieltjes studied in great detail $\;\displaystyle\zeta(x)-\frac 1{x-1}$ and $\displaystyle\int \frac {\zeta(x)-\frac 12-\frac 1{x-1}}x\,dx\;$ after all). This function is analytic everywhere with just the (important) drawback that the [zeros don't appear so neat](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261334/sum-of-stieltjes-constants). Cheers,

Comment: Nice answer. Do you suspect a closed form exists? In the case of the differential Zeta function, evaluating ln(2)+ln(3)+ln(4)+...=ln(sqrt(2*pi)). So one would suspect a closed form for the reciprocals also exists.

Comment: It's quite funny how about 4-5 people seem to answer all of my MSE questions. Small world!

Comment: @ElieBergman: I didn't find a closed form yet (using the $300$ first digits) and wouldn't bet on its existence (concerning the series many will return a closed form like $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \zeta(n)-1=1$ but integrals look harder perhaps because $\zeta(s)$ is often multiplied by $\Gamma(s)$ not sure...). Concerning the small world you are meeting people attracted by $\zeta$ and divergent series in these cases. Excellent continuation!

Answer (score 3):

$\ln(x)$ is smaller than $x$ for all positive values.

By that logic we can say that $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ is larger than $\frac{1}{x}$ for all positive x's

This means that $\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}+\frac{1}{\ln(4)}+...$ is larger than  $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...$

We know that $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...$ diverges and equals an infinite sum, and since $\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}+\frac{1}{\ln(4)}+...$ is larger than that infinite sum, we can conclude that $\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}+\frac{1}{\ln(4)}+...$ is an infinite sum.

Comment: The question is asking for the regularized sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$$
The comparison test, available [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+infty+of+%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cln%28n%2B1%29%7D), shows that this is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\ln k \le k \quad\forall k \ge 2,
$$
it follows that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\ln k}\ge \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k}=\infty.
$$

Comment: I don't really understand why my answer was downvoted. Could you please tell me where my mistake is!

Comment: I think I have confused everyone in this question. I am asking for the analytic continuation of the sum. Your argument is correct, but I am asking for something completely different.

Comment: I edited it because as it stands your proof isn't correct, $-2^k \leq k$ $\forall k \geq 2$ but obviously $-\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^k}$ does exist. You need that ln$ k$ is positive as well for it to actually follow.

Comment: $\ln k$ is obviously positive because $k \ge 2$.