# explore the convergence of series with ln(n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Help me explore the convergence of red color rounded series. On [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDGqt.jpg) (the equation below) I used radical indication but it doesn't show me the result. What would be better to use?

$$\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\ln(n)}=\text{?}}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^3\ln(n)}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1^n}}{\sqrt[n]{3^n} \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}} = 1$$

Radical Cauchy indication does not help.

Comment: $$\left ( 3^n\right)^{1/n}=3$$

Comment: First note that your series should start with $n=2$ (since $\ln(1)=0$) and in this case the series may be rewritten as $\,\displaystyle\int_3^{\infty}(\zeta(x)-1)\,dx\approx 0.2379961002$. The computation is the same as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731828/find-the-regularized-sum-frac1-ln2-frac1-ln3-frac1-ln4/731893#731893) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737551/evaluating-int-2-infty-zetax-1-mathrmdx) but with the lower bound $0$ (or $2$) replaced by $3$.

Answer (score 6):

Use the comparison with the Riemann series
$$\frac1{n^3\ln n}\le \frac1{n^3}\quad\text{for $n$ large enough}$$

Comment: It gives me a Limit( 1/ln(n) ) = 0. What it's mean? It means that the series diverg? Or not ? Can You explain me? Thanks

Comment: Your series is convergent since the Riemann series $\displaystyle \sum_n \frac1{n^3}$ is convergent ($3>1$)

Comment: Understood. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since $\log (n) >1$ as soon as $n \geq 3$, you can write $$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^3 \log (n)}=\frac{1}{8 \log (2)}+\sum _{n=3}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^3 \log (n)}$$ and now use the comparison suggested by Sami Ben Romdhane.

**Added after Raymond Manzoni's comments**

Just for entertainment, $$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta (3)-\frac{9}{8}=0.077057$$ So,$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^3 \log (n)}=0.237996 \le \frac{1}{8 \log (2)}+\zeta (3)-\frac{9}{8}=0.257394$$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. Oooops !

Comment: I compare these two expresions as Sami Ben Romdhane suggested me. 1st is bigger than 2nd. When I take a limit(1st / 2nd) it equals 0. So what it's mean?

Comment: @Luchnik: the idea is that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1} \frac 1{n^x}$ is convergent for $x>1$ (in your case $x=3$ and the previous sum is $\zeta(3)$). Your sum (starting with $n=2$) is positive and upper bounded by a convergent sum so...